# Add accessory view below navigation bar title in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationview

I’m trying to add an accessory view embedded in a navigation bar *below the title*, which can be seen in the default iOS calendar app (the “s m t w t f s” row) or the GitHub mobile app:

[image: Gh1][image: Gh1]

And I’d like it to work along with the large title style navigation bar like the GH mobile.

`LazyVStack`’s `pinnedView` with a section header almost work, but I can’t get the background color to make it seemless with the navigation bar, even with the `ultraThinMaterial`. It also leaves the divider line between the pinned view and the bar.

Is there a way to achieve this layout?
Solutions in SwiftUI, SwiftUI+[Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), and UIKit are all welcome!

Comment: did you ever end up achieving this layout? Are you able to post a code snippet?

Comment: @BrandonStillitano I remember getting it working with a single section with a section header, where the header view contained my accessory views.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70739635/5252984

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `.safeAreaInset` view? This will have the stickiness you're looking for, and items in the "main" part of the view will take its height into account when rendering, so won't get obscured.

Here's a quick example I knocked up:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        List {
          ForEach(0 ..< 30) { item in
            Text("Hello, world!")
          }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Accessory View")
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
          AccessoryView()
        }
      }
    }
}

struct AccessoryView: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Button("Button") { }
      Button("Button") { }
      Button("Button") { }
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color(uiColor: .systemGroupedBackground))
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    .controlSize(.mini)
  }
}
```

You have to give the view a background otherwise it'll be transparent – but that background will (as long as it's a colour or a material) automatically extend into the navigation bar itself. Here's a GIF of the above code in action, where I've set the background to match the grouped list's background:

[image]

It's not perfect, especially as it looks distinct from the nav bar on scroll, but it might be useable for you?

Comment: I didn't know about the `safeAreaInset` view modifier. Although I got what I got what I wanted, using a single-section LazyVStack with geometry reader to select between empty background (large title) and `Material.bar` (inline title), I see where this solution can be used. The major downside is that the accessory view does not scroll down with the large title.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to replace the navigation bar with a custom one like this:

```
{
    ...
}
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            HStack() {
                Button {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                }

                Spacer()

                    Text(navigationTitle).font(.title2).bold()
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Spacer()
                
            }
           HStack {
                 Button("Button") { }
                 Button("Button") { }
                 Button("Button") { }
                 Spacer()
               }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            .bar
        )
    }
```

You will also have to set:

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

and do not set a navigation title:

```
// .navigationTitle("....")
```